# Syntax to get the Nth item in a list of custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

We have a custom post type `testimonial` and want to show the 1st, 2nd and 3rd in various bespoke locations on the page.

Here's how we would do it if we just wanted to loop over testimonials and show them one after another (this works):

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'testimonial');
$testimonials = new WP_Query( $args );
    while( $testimonials->have_posts() ) {
    $testimonials->the_post();
?>
    <li>
        <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
    </li>

<?php }?>
```

But to show only the first or only the third or the Nth? Here's what we've got so far (to obtain the first), it's obviously wrong:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'testimonial');
$testimonials = new WP_Query( $args );   
$testimonial1 =$testimonials[0]->the_post;
echo $testimonial1->the_content;
```

We get an error saying:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Query as array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make use of an offset to skip the first 2 posts if you need the third post only, and then set you `posts_per_page` to `1` to get only that specific post

You can try something like this in your arguments

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonial',
    'offset' => 2,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$testimonials = new WP_Query( $args );
    while( $testimonials->have_posts() ) {
    $testimonials->the_post();
?>
    <li>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </li>

<?php }
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

### EDIT

Before I start, a few notes on your code and my edited code. (*I have edited my original code to show a normal loop*).

- You don't need to use `echo get_the_content()`. You can just use `the_content()` directly
- Remember to reset your postdata after the loop with `wp_reset_postdata()`.

As requested in comments, here is the alternative syntax where you don't use the loop. Also, a note or two first:

- With this alternative syntax, you cannot use the template tags as they will not be available

You need to work with the [`WP_Post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) objects directly and use filters as described in the [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post#Accessing_the_WP_Post_Object)

- You don't need to reset postdata as you are not altering the globals

You can try

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonial',
    'offset' => 2,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$testimonials = new WP_Query( $args );

//Displays the title
echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $testimonials->posts[0]->post_title );

//Displays the content
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $testimonials->posts[0]->post_content );
```

Comment: thanks for answering. i considered something like that but it seemed inelegant. so is yours the best and only way to do it?

Comment: There is no other native way to do this if you need something this specifc. And it is the quickest way as well. The only other method would be to get a list of posts and then use normal php to get the desired post from the returned array of posts, but this is much slower that the method in my answer. Simply skipping posts is also not an option, as it is much slower

Comment: ok, so do i still need a `while` loop?

Comment: For easyness, yes. Or you can access the post by `$testimonials->posts[0]`

Comment: Pieter thanks for all the help ... what would a little bit more of the syntax look like for $testimonials->posts[0]? i've tried it and then tried to echo out the content but got nothing showing

Comment: See my edit with alternative syntax. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `current_post` property and the `rewind_posts()` method of the `WP_Query` class, to target the relevant post objects.

You could try playing with the following example (untested):

```
if( $testimonials->post_count >= 3 )
{
    // First post:
    $nr = 1;
    if( isset( $testimonials->posts[$nr-1] ) )
    {
        $testimonials->rewind_posts();
        $testimonials->current_post = $nr - 2;
        $testimonials->the_post();
        the_title();
    }

    // Third post:
    $nr = 3;
    if( isset( $testimonials->posts[$nr-1] ) )
    {
        $testimonials->rewind_posts();
        $testimonials->current_post = $nr - 2;
        $testimonials->the_post();
        the_title();
    }

    // Second post:
    $nr = 2;
    if( isset( $testimonials->posts[$nr-1] ) )
    {
        $testimonials->rewind_posts();
        $testimonials->current_post = $nr - 2;
        $testimonials->the_post();
        the_title();
    }  

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

You could also use it like this, with your current `while` loops:

```
$testimonials = new WP_Query( $args );

// First post:
$nr = 1; 
while( $testimonials->have_posts() && ( $nr - 2 ) === $testimonials->current_post ) {
    $testimonials->the_post();
    // ...
}

// Third post:
$nr = 3;
$testimonials->rewind_posts();
while( $testimonials->have_posts() && ( $nr - 2 ) === $testimonials->current_post ) {
    $testimonials->the_post();
    // ...
}

// Second post:
$nr = 2;
$testimonials->rewind_posts();
while( $testimonials->have_posts() && ( $nr - 2 ) === $testimonials->current_post ) {
    $testimonials->the_post();
    // ...
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Cool method if you need to randomly pic posts within the same query. Little bit to much if you need one post :-)